# Trying to add my first score counter (Python) (Beginner)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first post here. I'm a total beginner in coding and I've created a little game to get some sort of practice. I'm having trouble adding a score counter to it. I've seen some similar posts but I didn't manage to figure it out.

Also can you guys/girls give me some tips on my code, any feedback is welcome (tell me what I can improve etc.)

Here is the code:

```
import random
import time


def game():

    user_wins = 0
    user_loses = 0

    while True:
        try:
            number = int(input('Choose a number between 1 and 10: '))
            if 0 <= number <= 10:
                print('Rolling the dices {} time(s)!'.format(number))
                break
            else:
                print("That's not quite what we were looking for.")
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not quite what we were looking for.")

    user_number = random.randint(1, 50)
    computer_number = random.randint(1, 50)

    time.sleep(1)
    print("You've rolled {}".format(user_number))

    time.sleep(1)
    print('Bob rolled {}'.format(computer_number))

    if computer_number > user_number:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('Bob Won')
        user_loses += 1
    elif computer_number < user_number:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("You've Won!")
        user_wins += 1
    elif computer_number == user_number:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('Seems like we have a little situation')

    print("\nWins: {} \nLosses: {}".format(user_wins, user_loses))

    time.sleep(0.5)
    play_again = input(str("Would you like to play again (y/n)? "))
    if play_again == 'y':
        print("Ready?\n")
        game()
    else:
        print("\nThank you for playing.")


game()
```

I want to add something like Your score: 1-0 or something similar. I've made some progress on that but when looping the values reset..

Comment: You'll have to initialize the score before starting the `while` loop. If you intialize wihtin the while loop, it will be reset each time ...

Comment: The indentation is off in your code it makes it harder to read: what is the scope of `def game():`? But other than that, you haven't shown what you actually tried. Where is your `score` variable, and how are you trying to update it? WIthout that, it is impossible to know what the exact problem is. You should make a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) and update your Q.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow, and to Python! Some advice on how to write a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. yes, the code it's not properly Indented, I'll edit it. I didn't include my attempt of score counting, but it was like this: user_score = 0
bob_score = 0 and I had user/bob_score += 1 in the if/elif

Comment: @neuronet I've updated the code with my attempt on counting the score :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to programming! So I'm going to tell you *how* to implement it, so you can do it yourself as well :D. So here is what we will do:

We will have a variable outside the [scope(click here)](https://pythonspot.com/scope/) of the `while` loop to keep track of the score, say `score = 0`. 
And each time someone succeeds, gets the right answer, we will increase that, by saying, `score = score + 1`. But that takes too much time to type that right D: So python has a shortcut! You say `score += 1` somewhere in your code where you want to increase the score (in the `while True` loop, in this case). And then we will later print out the score (or anything) by referencing it:

`print( "Your final score was %s" % str(score) )` - I know, *what is that stupid `str()` for!?* It is because our `score` is an integer. Since we can add and do operations on it(yeah I know soo cool).

Aaaand thats it :). If you need any further help, don't hesitate to ask it. Good luck :D.

Comment: This is a simple problem that doesn't require globals. Global variables should be avoided until absolutely necessary, and even then, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I just meant outside the scope of that loop. Let me edit the answer. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will try to implement this.

Comment: @KidDoesCodingAndHasNoFriends I've edited the code here with the way I've tried to count the score, can you take a look? It does work after the first round, however if I choose to play again the values are reset to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Move this line before the while loop starts. 
    number = int(input('Choose a number between 1 and 10: '))
Also, it prompts to input between 1-10 but the if statement allows 0-10.
To add a counter start by assigning an initial to score to both players to 0.

---

user_number_score = 0

---

inside the If statements that determine who won the round for example if the user won add...

---

```
user_number_score = user_number_score + 1
```

Comment: Short form: `user_number_score += 1`

Comment: @eyllanesc The thing is that it's not counting more than 1 round, if you choose to play again, the value is reset to 0 for some reason.

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry, I was commenting about what Jose Lopez said, and replied to you instead, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do it. I had to start over, re-done the code from scratch and it's better looking too. Thank you all for the feedback.

[Added it as image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLs7r.jpg)